# How to upgrade Apache HTTP Server from version 2.4.16 to the latest stable version i.e. 2.4.18 on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, apache2, webserver, apache2.4

I'm basically a **PHP Developer** by profession and I'm using **LAMP** on my machine.
I'm using **64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** on my machine.

I'm using Apache HTTP Server on my machine. To check it's version I executed following command and got following result :

```
~$ apachectl -V
```

**Output is as below :**

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:47
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

From the above output you can see that I'm using older version of Apache HTTP Server on my machine. I want to get it upgraded to the latest stable version i.e. Apache HTTP Server 2.4.18.

Can someone please tell me in detailed step-by-step manner how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The latest Apache2 release for Trusty is 2.4.7 ([see here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty-updates&keywords=apache2)), so to get any higher at this moment, you'll need to add a PPA source.

You can add Ondrej's PPA, to get to the most stable version.

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Still it's showing me version 2.4.16 only. Why?

Comment: @user2839497 since Ubuntu 14.04 comes with [Apache 2.4.7](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/apache2), and you have 2.4.16, that depends on how you obtained 2.4.16 in the first place.

Comment: @muru:That I don't know.  In last week I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04. That  only I know.